# What statistical test to use for this scenario?

Tags: anova, t-test, spss, intervention-analysis

Here's my problem.

--ONLY One group--

All fill-out pre-test.
All participants given intervention.
Complete a post-test.
Return in 2-weeks to complete another post-test to determine if intervention effects sustained.

My question is whether intervention has an effect (which in comparing pre- and post-test, leads me to believe I can use paired sample t-test)
But having the 2-week post-test, does this mean that I will be using repeated measures ANOVA?
I haven't had research in a while, and was looking around online and getting frustrated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated measures ANOVA is to be used when the same subjects are used for each treatment. On the other hand, One-way ANOVA is used to test for differences among two or more independent groups (means). In the case that you mention, Repeated measures ANOVA would be more appropriate.